# Two separate query lists in the same view in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to have 2 separate query lists on the same page but with different filters. First list must be played and the second one paused. This is what I came up with in my views.py file but it throws an error like this: **UnboundLocalError at /
local variable 'formset_paused' referenced before assignment**

```
def home_view(request):
    #campaigns in progress
    queryset = Campaign.objects.filter(is_active=True, completion_percent__lt=100)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form_type = request.POST.get('id')
        if form_type == 'campaign_status':
            formset = CampaignStatusFormSet(
                request.POST, request.FILES,
                queryset=queryset,
            )
            formset.save()
    else:
        formset = CampaignStatusFormSet(queryset=queryset)

    campaigns_and_forms = list(zip(queryset, formset))


    #paused campaigns
    queryset_paused = Campaign.objects.filter(is_active=False, completion_percent__lt=100)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form_type_paused = request.POST.get('id_paused')
        if form_type_paused == 'campaign_status_paused':
            formset_paused = CampaignStatusFormSet(
                request.POST, request.FILES,
                queryset=queryset_paused,
            )
            formset_paused.save()
    else:
        formset_paused = CampaignStatusFormSet(queryset=queryset_paused)

    paused_campaigns_and_forms = list(zip(queryset_paused, formset_paused))

    context = {
        'formset': formset,
        'formset_paused': formset_paused,
        'campaigns_and_forms': campaigns_and_forms,
        'paused_campaigns_and_forms': paused_campaigns_and_forms,
    }

    return render(request, 'campaigns_in_progress.html', context)
```

Here are the tables in my template where I make those 2 lists.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bright table-bordered align-middle">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Nazwa</th>
            <th scope="col">Temat</th>
            <th scope="col">Nadawca</th>
            <th scope="col">Procent Realizacji</th>
            <th scope="col">Start Kampani</th>
            <th scope="col">Stan</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <form method="post" id="campaign_status"> {% csrf_token %}
        <input type='hidden' value='campaign_status' name='id'>
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for campaign, form in campaigns_and_forms %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ campaign.campaign_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ campaign.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ campaign.topic }}</td>
            <td>{{ campaign.sender }}</td>
            <td>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: {{campaign.completion_percent}}%;" aria-valuenow="{{campaign.completion_percent}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">{{campaign.completion_percent}}%</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>{{ campaign.start_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.as_p }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </form>
    </tbody>
</table>

<h4>Kampanie zatrzymane</h4>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bright table-bordered align-middle">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Nazwa</th>
            <th scope="col">Temat</th>
            <th scope="col">Nadawca</th>
            <th scope="col">Procent Realizacji</th>
            <th scope="col">Start Kampani</th>
            <th scope="col">Stan</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <form method="post" id="campaign_status_paused"> {% csrf_token %}
        <input type='hidden' value='campaign_status_paused' name='id_paused'>
    {{ formset_paused.management_form }}
    {% for campaign, form in paused_campaigns_and_forms %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ campaign.campaign_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ campaign.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ campaign.topic }}</td>
            <td>{{ campaign.sender }}</td>
            <td>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: {{campaign.completion_percent}}%;" aria-valuenow="{{campaign.completion_percent}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">{{campaign.completion_percent}}%</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>{{ campaign.start_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.as_p }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </form>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Before adding the second query and the second table everything worked.

So basically what I want is when the is_active filter is equal to True the campaign should be in the first list. If it's False then it should jump to the other. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73356460/17562044) question.

Comment: Pass `formset_paused=""` as empty string just above POST method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `request.method == "POST"` but `form_type_paused != 'campaign_status_paused'`, the `formset_paused` variable is never assigned. But you try to access it here:

```py
...
paused_campaigns_and_forms = list(zip(queryset_paused, formset_paused))
...
```

That is where the error comes from.

Comment: But in "campaigns_in_progress" its the same but it doesnt throw this error

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you. You are not setting up your variables correctly. You need to ensure that a variable will always be assigned **before** accessing it. Other than that, if you are unsure, what data exactly is submitted with your form, add some temporary print statements to your view functions like `print(request.POST)` and check the log.

Comment: @low_ratio Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73356460/local-variable-user-referenced-before-assignment-error-in-django-function) question?

Comment: Dear Answerer, I'd suggest to you call user's name by @ so that your comment could go as a notification.