# "local variable 'form_b' referenced before assignment django"

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

```
def register(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.POST.get('submit') == 'sign_up':
            form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
            form = RegisterForm()
        elif request.POST.get('submit') == 'log_in':
            form1 = LogInForm(request=request, data=request.POST)
            if form1.is_valid():
                uname = form1.cleaned_data['username']
                upass = form1.cleaned_data['password']
                user = authenticate(username=uname, password=upass)
                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/')
        else:
            form_b = LogInForm()
            form = RegisterForm()
        return render(request, 'auth.html', {'form': form, 'form1': form_b})
```

This above is my view function

```
<form class="loginForm" action="" method="POST" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %} 
    {% for field in form %}
       <p> {{field.label_tag}}  {{field}} </p>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="btnLogin" name='submit' value='sign_up'>Sing Up</button>
 </form>
 <form class="loginForm" action="" method="post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form1 %}
       <p> {{field.label_tag}}  {{field}} </p>
    {% endfor %}
 <button  class="btnLogin" type="submit"  name='submit' value='log_in'>Log In </button>
 </form>
```

rendering two forms in a view function code is working fine but when i click on signup this error occur which says "local variable 'form_b' referenced before assignment django"

Comment: Your first two if statements does not define form_b.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [local variable 'user' referenced before assignment error in django function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73356460/local-variable-user-referenced-before-assignment-error-in-django-function)

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign this variable in every possible situation if you use it in the end OR just add exclusive return for the part where it exists. I your particular situation I suggest change `form_b` to `form1` and move them in front of `if not request.user.is_authenticated` condition:

```
def register(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        form1 = LogInForm()
        form = RegisterForm()
        if request.POST.get('submit') == 'sign_up':
            ...
        elif request.POST.get('submit') == 'log_in':
            ...
        return render(request, 'auth.html', {'form': form, 'form1': form1})
```

In this way you will make sure, that both of them exist. If another condition will be `True`, then it will override empty form creation.